# To print GunZip FileName /PathName and Selected Rows :

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to print first 2 rows from all the files located in the Directory/Sub Directories  along with File Name and Path Name. 
All are *.gz extension files. Having around 10000 files in that Directory/Sub Directories  and having multiple sub directories.

For Example:

```
Dir:home/Test
```

sample_Test.csv.gz

```
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300
50,Jan,500
```

Dir: home/Test/Feb

sample_feb.csv.gz

```
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400
40,Feb,800
60,Feb,1200
```

Dir: home/Test/Mar/Data

sample_mar.csv.gz

```
10,Mar,200
20,Mar,400
40,Mar,800
60,Mar,1200
```

Expected Output:

```
Filename:sample_jan.csv.gz , PathName: home/Test
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300

Filename:sample_feb.csv.gz , PathName: home/Test/Feb
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400

Filename:sample_mar.csv.gz , PathName: home/Test/Mar/Data
10,Mar,200
20,Mar,400
```

Have tried below command and Partial .

```
for file in *.gz; do echo "Filename: $file"; zcat "$file" | head -2 ; done
```

Would like to run the command in "home" directory which would search the files in present directory and below sub-directories.
Looking for your suggestions !!!

Comment: So what's wrong with the command you have now?

Comment: This command searching the files in the current directory only, would like to know how to print Pathname as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand your `for` loop with `find`:

```
for FILE in `find home -type f -name *.gz`; do
  echo "Filename: `basename $FILE` , PathName: `dirname $FILE`"
  zcat $FILE | head -2
done
```

The `type f` looks for files only.

`basename` strips the directory and suffixes leaving the file name.

`dirname` strips the non-directory suffix from the file name leaving the directory path.